# Persistent Error 500: Authentication backend unknown error with Terraform on Google Firebase Project Creation

Tags: firebase, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have these [Google Project](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project) and [Firebase Project](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/firebase_project) resources in Terraform:

```Terraform
resource "google_project" "main" {
  provider = google-no-user-project-override

  name       = var.category_pascal_case
  org_id     = var.gcp_organization_id
  project_id = var.project_id
  billing_account = var.gcp_billing_account_id

  labels = {
    "firebase" = "enabled"
  }
}

resource "google_firebase_project" "main" {
  provider = google-beta
  project  = var.project_id
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Error: Error checking if Firebase is already enabled: googleapi: Error
> 500: Authentication backend unknown error.

More details:

- I thought it was a transient error on Google's side but it has been happening for many days now.
- Google Logs Explorer shows no errors.
- If I remove `google_firebase_project` then `terraform apply` is successful, so this could be the root of the problem somehow
- I have tried adding `roles/owner` at the organisation and project level so I don't think it's a permissions issue.

What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

This was being run inside Github Action CI/CD with the [google-github-actions/auth](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth).

The solution was to use Service Account JSON auth instead of Workload Identity Federation methods.

Read more about this [bug here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1377).